# Why do I get "is not defined" error in my homework code?

Tags: javascript

In the below homework assignment I have done everything I can think of from the chapter but it won't work at all I feel like I am missing something or have I messed up somewhere because even the cursor wont change when I hover over the nested lists.

One of the instructions says:

> "Using the id property of the list item experiencing the mousedown event, extract the index number with the parseInt() function"

but it doesn't seem that what I did is correct.

```
window.onload = setup; 

function setup() { 
    var questions = document.querySelectorAll('ol li'); 

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { 
        questions[i].id = i + "phrase"; 
        questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish(questions[i]);
        questions[i].onmouseup = showFrench(questions[i]); 
        questions[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
}

function showEnglish() { 
    var phraseNumber = parseInt(questions[i].id); 

    phraseNumber.innerHTML = english[phraseNumber]; 
    phraseNumber.style.font = "italic"; 
    phraseNumber.style.color = "rgb(191, 22, 31)";
}

function showFrench() { 
    var phraseNumber = parseInt(questions[i].id); 

    phraseNumber.innerHTML = french[phraseNumber]; 
    phraseNumber.style.fontStyle = ""; 
    phraseNumber.style.color = "";
}
```

I get an error saying `questions` is not defined at   `questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish(questions[i]);` and
`var phraseNumber = parseInt(questions[i].id);`

I have been doing my coding in Notepad++ If that matters.

Html segment:

```
<ol>
           <li>Cet h&#244;tel n'est pas loin de la Tour Eiffel.</li>
           <li>A quelle heure arrive le train?</li>
           <li>Nous attendons l'autobus depuis une demi-heure.</li>
           <li>Ce repas est d&#233;licieux.</li>
           <li>Quel jour va-t-elle arriver?</li>
           <li>Nous avons onze minutes avant le d&#233;part du train!</li>
           <li>Habiter dans un pays &#233;tranger est une bonne exp&#233;rience.</li>
           <li>Excusez-moi! Je suis en retard!</li>
           <li>Est-ce que ce taxi est libre?</li>
           <li>Faites attention quand vous descendez l'escalier.</li>
        </ol>
```

Comment: the questions variable is `document.querySelectorAll('ol li')` , what is your HTML like?

Comment: `questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish(questions[i]);` You're invoking the function instead of assigning it as a handler. Do `questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish;` instead, and then inside the handler use `this` instead of `questions[i]` to reference the clicked element in the handler. Same with the `showFrench` function

Comment: @hackerrdave I updated the main post with the html segment that its based off.

Comment: @squint I'm trying that but seem to get a new error: "Cannot set property 'font' of undefined"

Comment: You are confusion local and global variables. And you are not properly assigning event handlers.

Comment: @Fuey500: That's because `phraseNumber` is the result of `parseInt()`, which is a number, not an element. Use `this` to access the element. `this.innerHTML...`, `this.style...`

Comment: the function call showEnglish(questions[i]), but in your function declaration, it does not accept any parameter.

Comment: @squint Thank you so much and everyone else It's solved now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you assign an event handler properly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    ....
    questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish(questions[i]);
    ...
}
```

Instead change it to this:

```
questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish;
```

You are assigning the function as an event handler, not calling it at that particular moment. Note that when you add the parenthesis `fn()` you are calling a function.

Now you will have to update the `showEnglish()` function to reflect that.

```
function showEnglish() { 
    var phraseNumber = parseInt(this.id); // Here
    ...
}
```

Note that I used the `this` keyword to refer to the element.

The same process goes for `onmouseup` and the `showFrench` function

Comment: Thank you so much!